# Pandas removing whitespace in part of string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am writing a regex code to remove the whitespace for financial values of the string in pandas dataframe. Let's suppose a pandas dataframe called df and a column "detail" is in the dataframe df.

For example, the column contains string like:

"maximum USD 1 000 000 per house as respects Detroit"

"minimum $ 3 000 000 per destroyed house due to Earthquake"

I tried using str.replace method in pandas, with regex applied. However,

```
df['detail'].str.replace(r"(USD)\s*(\d+\s*)+(\d+)", r"USD\s\d+\d+", regex=True)

df['detail'].str.replace(r"(\$)\s*(\d+\s*)+(\d+)", r"\$\s\d+\d+", regex=True)
```

will return

"maximum USD\s\d+\d+ per house as respects Detroit"

"minimum \$\s\d+\d+ per destroyed house due to Earthquake"
rather than replacing the number with the right format.

The expected result is to remove the whitespace for financial values and return:

"maximum USD 1000000 per house as respects Detroit"

"minimum $ 3000000 per destroyed house due to Earthquake"

What code should I try to remove whitespace inside the financial values? The actual data is huge so manual work is going to be immense.

**Solved:**

Thanks for the answers, I used the following code and it works well. In big data it is possible for the USD/$ to have multiple whitespaces before the financial number (Or it could be 0), so \s+ or \s* provide a safe approach for this problem.

```
df['detail'] = df['detail'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+(\d{3})', r'\1', x))
```

Comment: Most regex patterns don't make sense as replacements. For example, you have `\d+` in your replacement pattern. What digit should that resolve to? How many of them? If you just want to keep what was originally in the input string, you can use a capturing group `( ... )` and then reference each group with `\1`, `\2`, etc.

Comment: Also, instead of trying to match the pattern of your entire input string, it might be easier to use regex to match the specific sub patterns that you're trying to replace. In this particular case, it looks like you're trying to find whitespaces in between two numerals.

Comment: Exactly, I only want to remove whitespace inside the numerals, they could be 10 000, or 10 000 000, or 1 000 000 000, etc.

Comment: Anyway, match `(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)` and replace with nothing (`""`) should work for you. If it does, just let me know and I'll write an answer with an explanation.

Comment: I think you are looking for `df['detail'].str.replace(r'(USD|\$)\s*(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)', lambda x: "{} {}".format(x.group(1), x.group(2).replace(" ", "")))`. Instead of `x.group(2).replace(" ", "")`, you may use `re.sub(r'\s+', '', x.group(2))` if there can be really other whitespace chars, not just spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for your case:

```
>>> import re
>>> phrases = ["minimum $ 3 000 000 per destroyed house due to Earthquake",
"maximum USD 1 000 000 per house as respects Detroit",
"You own me $ 1 000 000 000 dollars" ]
>>> for phrase in phrases:
...     re.sub(r'\s(\d{3})', r'\1', phrase)
... 
'minimum $ 3000000 per destroyed house due to Earthquake'
'maximum USD 1000000 per house as respects Detroit'
'You own me $ 1000000000 dollars'
>>>
```

Tested also with this:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s(\d{3})', r'\1', 'This is a really big number 3 000 434 132 131 111 333 right?')
'This is a really big number 3000434132131111333 right?'
>>>
```

Comment: For e.g. 1 000 000 000 instead of 1 000 000 it will strip the space between 0 and per, too ...

Comment: I just fixed that. Check the new version.

Comment: I just realize we need to strip spaces from every 3 consecutive digits.

Answer (score 2):

the one line answer for your problem will be using apply function in pandas.

```
import re
df['detail'] = df['detail'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\d)\s+(\d)',r'\1\2', x))
```

Comment: I think you could take care of any string related error  using the following, otherwise nice answer:                                     df['detail'] = df['detail'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\d)\s+(\d)',r'\1\2', x))